# Stack Overflow (In Portuguese) listed inconsistently as public and private beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase, private-beta

According to the [area51 list of betas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), Stack Overflow (in Portuguese) is in public beta:

[image: screenshot Stack Overflow (in Portuguese) public beta]

Yet when clicking through, it is reported as private beta:

[image: screenshot Stack Overflow (in Portuguese) private beta]

The latter appears correct when clicking through once more.

Comment: It does appear in the realtime question websocket, and sometimes even on the realtime question page itself (IIRC)

Comment: The bar progress appears to be automatic, based on how many days passed since private beta began, assuming that after 7 days the site goes to public beta. That's the case most of the times, but this one is a rare exception.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think it shows *public beta* automatically after 7+ days, or I would have noticed this earlier and more often.

Answer (score 2):

The site will soon move to public beta, will not fix for now.